# Has anyone come across a geometric interpretation for fractional exponents of pi?

Tags: geometry, pi

Once in a while I'll see pi, not squared, but to a fractional power. For instance when dealing with a bell curve with its integral to infinity, you obtain $$ \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$
When you evaluate certain elliptic integrals or fractional inputs of the gamma function like $\Gamma(\frac{2}{3})$, you might obtain a $$\pi^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

Getry: in Sterling's formula which is $$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} (\frac{n}{e})^n$$ you can see the square root of pi.

But, where do fractional powers of pi occur geometrically? In what physical circumstances do these uncommon numbers like this typically occur? If I drew a circle...where is that theorem containing a fractional power of pi that relates its circumference to its diameter? Or maybe it's not a circle, maybe it pertains to a lemiscate, or maybe it pertains to  ellipse, but there has to be some something that can make sense of these numbers, they aren't random.

Comment: Maybe in non-planar geometry the ratio of circumference to diameter contains a $\pi^\gamma$ term.

Comment: @ja72 Pi, specifically to the power of the Euler–Mascheroni constant? I've never seen any application of pi to the power of another transcendental number before, I'm interested in knowing where that occurs.

Comment: No just some arbitrary real number $\gamma$. You can ignore my comment.

Comment: @ja72 Is using a lower case gamma for an arbitrary constant common in your region? Normally I see people use "a" or "b" or "n."

Comment: The side length of a  square with equal area as a circle with radius 1?

Comment: One more non-geometric appearance: Stirling's formula. $n!$ is asymptotic to $n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Yeah I think that is one instance, so perhaps these numbers pertain to generalized instances where curved shapes are transformed to polygons, or where some algebraic curve is forced into a straight line...but that sounds like arclength, so the arc-length of an algebraic function...but that sounds like an elliptic integral most likely...

Comment: Humanity has been at the puzzle of figuring out how to interpret this geometrically for a while now. If you'll take a suggestion: Don't spend more than 2000 years trying to square the circle. It's not possible. 

I thought the wiki on squaring the circle was interesting. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle

Answer (score 1):

To generalize Professor Vector's comment, the $d$-dimensional hypersphere of radius 1 has hypervolume $A_d\pi^s$ for some easily computed rational constant $A_d$, where $s$ is the integer part of $d/2$ – see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball). Then the hypercube with the same hypervolume has side $A_d^{1/d}\pi^{s/d}$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, one generalization of the volume of a shape as you increase the dimension you extend it in (e.g. the area of circle, then a volume sphere, the hypervolume of a hypersphere), those interior volumes of n-dimensional spheres are generalized by the gamma function and their radius under the formula $$V_n(R) = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)}$$, perhaps there is a way to combine these two concepts. The questions still remains then: what do these hyper shapes have to do with elliptic integrals? And is it a coincidence that the gamma function is involved?

Comment: Why should hyperspheres have anything to do with elliptic integrals?

Comment: Because the gamma function at fractional values occurs as a solution to certain elliptic integrals, and most fractional values of the gamma function also yield fractional powers of pi, as do certain elliptic integrals. So somehow, generalizing dimensional extensions of shapes is related to evaluating the arclength of algebraic functions, in some instances at least. I can only guess that this is related to some larger web of anisotropic topology that hasn't been researched much.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add an $R^n$ term as a coefficient of the right side of the equation.